# Pandas Multiindex not working with read_csv and datetime objects

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, multi-index

I have a problem loading a dataframe from csv when I have a multiindex with more than one date in it.

I am running the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
date1 = datetime.date.today()
date2 = datetime.date.today().replace(month=1)
date_cols=['date1', 'date2']
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[date1],[date2]])

#create dataframe with a single row
df= pd.DataFrame([{'date1':date1, 'date2':date2, 'a':1, 'b':2}])
df.set_index(date_cols, inplace=True)
#print the single row -> correct
print df.loc[index]

# write to csv and load it again
df.to_csv('df.csv')
dfr = pd.read_csv('df.csv', parse_dates=date_cols, dayfirst=True)
dfr.set_index(date_cols, inplace=True)
# print the single row -> incorrect, shows nan,
print dfr.loc[index]
```

Whilst I expect to get the same output, i.e. the single row in the dataframe,
the second print statement prints out nan, because the index is not in the dataframe.
When running df.index, I see that the multiindex object contains the two dates, but now also holds time information, where the time is 00:00:00

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is subtlely different.

```
In [31]: df.index.levels[0]
Out[31]: Index([2014-07-31], dtype='object')

In [32]: dfr.index.levels[0]
Out[32]: 
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2014-07-31]
Length: 1, Freq: None, Timezone: None
```

The initial creation (using `MultiIndex.from_product` is using `datetimes`. In a multi-index creation I suppose this could cause an automatic DatetimeIndex creation, rather that a plain `Index` of `datetimes`.

When reading it back in a proper `DatetimeIndex` is created. I'll open an issue to think about this. See [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/7888)

Comment: When I initialize date1 and date2 to be pandas.datetime objects instead of datetime.datetime objects it works fine.
Thanks for the very fast response btw

Comment: yep, they are then ``Timestamps`` (its equivalent but not identical to ``datetimes``)